# Javascript clear input field on moving focus from one input field to the other

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following code on a input number field:

```
<input class="quantity_container" v-model="length.quantity" 
    type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" 
    onfocus="if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';"/>
```

The code to clear the field works if no other input field was in focus before I switched to the new input field that has a '0' in it. The page has many input fields and I can’t access them by name unfortunately. I’ve checked and the onfocus is getting called, but the field is never cleared when it is '0' and moving focus from one input field to the other.

It only clears if I tap away and remove focus on the last input field and then gain focus on the new one.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could possibly be because you have VueJS model bindings. You should handle the validation in your Vue component / instance, possibly by using a [computed property setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

Comment: Can't duplicate. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/f6191jnq/). Please provide a demo of your proble, such as a link to your site, a JSfiddle, a CodePen, or a StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: @Phil - I think you're right given that ChrisHappy has shown in his example that it isn't just JS related. Thanks to both of you for these hints. I'll give the computed property a go to see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement this by creating a [custom input component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events). For example

```
Vue.component('quantity-input', {
  template: '<input type="number" class="quantity_container" inputmode="numeric" ref="input" :value="value" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" />',
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    updateValue: function(value) {
      var formattedValue = value == 0 ? '' : value
      if (formattedValue !== value) {
        this.$refs.input.value = formattedValue
      }
      this.$emit('input', formattedValue)
    }
  }
})
```

You can then simply use

```
<quantity-input v-model="length.quantity"></quantity-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

use onblur to clear the field, The blur event occurs when the  field loses focus. in your case it will be like

```
<input class="quantity_container" v-model="length.quantity" 
    type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" 
    onblur="if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';"/>
```

if your input fields has 0 value at the time of page loading, you can clear them as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[value="0"]').val('');
});
```